# How to Save as PDF using TexMaker

Tags: pdftex, texmaker

I have written a paper using pdflatex in TexMaker, so I have no problem viewing my document as a PDF. However, I am not sure how to SAVE the file as a PDF document and then view it outside of TexMaker. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `pdflatex` creates a `pdf` file in the same folder as your `tex` file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You don't need to save it. The file is created before you view it. That is, it is the PDF which you are viewing.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it isn't actually a question; a pdf has already been generated.

Comment: @IanThompson This seems to be a popular question; maybe it could be reopened again for those who have it?

Comment: Yes please. It would be a lot helpful if you can reopen the question and someone answers it